# no html:5 option when I specify the first < in a program

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm new to VS code, and I'm writing my first programs in HTML, but when I write the first < , the dropdown menu show a list of item that not comprises HTML:5 (the menu show only the option HTML), so I have to code maually the skeleton of the programs. Can somebody help me ? I'm using windows 10 and the release of vs code is 1.85.1 (the last one). Thanks a lot.

I solved the problem coding manually what the option HTML:5 makes automatically, but this is not a real solution. I've tried to close vs code and then restart it, and also to close windows and then restart it, but I had no results. I'm really getting crazy.

Comment: A [Visual Studio Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=html&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) might help, but picking the right one is opinion based... 

Comment: Try typing a `!`  (no preceding `<`), that is the emmet abbreviation that gives you the same code as `html:5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html:5` is an Emmet Abbreviation suggestion. If you want to get an Emmet Abbreviation Suggestion, you shouldn't type the opening angle bracket for an HTML tag- that will cause suggestions to be for HTML tag names.

Note that if you're doing that part right and still don't get the Emmet abbreviation suggestion, then check your `emmet.showAbbreviationSuggestions` setting. It defaults to `true`, but you may have accidentally set it to `false`.

Also note that `html:5` is the same abbreviation as `!`, so if one doesn't work, as a workaround, you could try the other.

---

Also, I feel the need to comment on [the asker's self-answer](/a/77718232/11107541), which says

> I've found that Bard says the menu item "html:5" has been removed from version 1.49.0, released on 1/12/2023.

This is why if you don't know what you're talking about, you shouldn't trust an LLM. [VS Code 1.49](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49) was released near the end of August 2020- not early January 2023. And the part about `html:5` being removed is just nonsense. [VS Code's builtin emmet extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/emmet) uses [the `@vscode/emmet-helper` package](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-emmet-helper), which uses [emmet itself](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet), and `html:5` is still right there in the latest commit at the time of this writing. See the file [`src/snippets/html.json`](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/93b320920fd09dee436acf4c26ef15f6ed9f80dd/src/snippets/html.json#L153).

Comment: Thanks, thanks a lot for your answer. I'm completely new to VS code and even to understand the answer took me a while (but it was well worth it). The option "emmet.showAbbreviationSuggestions" was set to false, and I've changed to true. Then I code ! as first character, and the skeleton of the program was shown. My only problem now is to know what character I have to code to see htlm:5 as option in a dropdown menu. Thanks again.